# how to convert pdf into excel?

Tags: master-pdf-editor

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
I have a pdf statement and want to convert it to an excel file format.
Is there any OCR engine/software that can accomplish this task?
Can someone please advise.

Comment: A "PDF *statement*"? What's that? You mean some kind of bank statement? Can you show us an example of the file?

Comment: hi ,i mean pdf file!!!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to open the pdf file with PDFedit, then save the file as text file.

If you want to install the PDFedit just type in a terminal the following.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pdfedit
```

You can then import the text file into OpenOffice.org (or LibreOffice) Calc etc and save the resulting spreadsheet in the desired format (eg. ods, xls etc).

To import the text file into Calc, open the Text Import dialog box via the Insert, Sheet from File menu. Then choose either "Fixed width" or the "Separated by" options as appropriate for your data. Note that if you use the "Fixed width" option you can set each column width via the "Fields" preview of the box.

Comment: `sudo apt install pdfedit` doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04